# setInputType on EditTextPreference

Tags: java, android, android-preferences

how can i add the "setInputType" propety to an EditTextPreference (my goal is to set the input type to numbers only), i've tried:

```
editTextPref.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

but this only seems to work for EditTexts, not EditTextPreferences

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can retrieve the EditText from the Preference and from there setInputTypes or use KeyListeners to inform the keyboard:

```
EditText et = (EditText) editTextPref.getEditText();
et.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance());
```

Answer (score 4):

If all you really need is a single inputType for your editTextPreference you could set it in the XML with android:inputType="number" or android:inputType="numberDecimal".

Example:

```
<EditTextPreference
        android:defaultValue="130"
        android:dialogMessage="@string/upper_limit_hint"
        android:dialogTitle="@string/upper_limit_text"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:key="UPPER_LIMIT"
        android:maxLength="4"
        android:summary="@string/upper_limit_hint"
        android:title="@string/upper_limit_text" />
```

Also, thanx to Dave's suggestion above, I was able to achieve this programmatically by assigning the EditTextPreference to a TextView (I was unable to use an EditText).

Example:

```
EditTextPreference editTextPreference = (EditTextPreference) preference;
        TextView etpTextView = (TextView) editTextPreference.getEditText();
        // If I want entry with decimal capability
        etpTextView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
        // or if I want entry without decimal capability
        etpTextView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

1. call getEditText() from your editTextPref
2. then set input type to that.